# No Vendor folder or composer.lock when creating new projects - Learning Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

1. Installed PHP and Composer
2. `composer global require laravel/installer`
3. Added environment variable Path for PHP
4. When running `laravel new example-app`

No `vendor` folder or `composer.lock` being created, and I get an error:

> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - C:\php8\php.ini

I don't see a `php.ini` in my `php8` folder.

Tried reinstalling it all and ran a few other commands on StackOverflow but nothing working so far.

Comment: You are clearly getting an error, that is why it is not creating a `vendor` folder nor `composer.lock` file. Could you share the full output?

Comment: In console `php --ini` show you where php.ini file. Check Laravel server-requirements [link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#server-requirements)

Comment: Please share the **full and exact** error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem